# User Tracking with JavaScript

Tags: 2010, javascript, sharepoint-on-prem

I'm looking to capture two pieces of information in our on-premise installation of SharePoint 2010 Foundation. I would like to be able to include in the master page a simple script that logs the logged in user(we use Active Directory), and the hostname they are accessing the page from, that saves the information to a file somewhere.

I figured I would use a modification of the below code. Could someone help me out with this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");
    var context = null;
    var web = null;
    var currentUser = null;

    function getWebUserData() {
        context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = context.get_web();
        currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
        currentUser.retrieve();
        context.load(web);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), 
             Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
    }

    function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
        var userObject = web.get_currentUser();
        alert('User name:' + userObject.get_title() + '\n Login Name:' + 
                 userObject.get_loginName());
    }

    function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {
        alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, You need to load 'currentUser' variable in the load function not the 'web' variable.

Below is the code you can try.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");    

    function getWebUserData() {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();        
        currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
        context.load(currentUser);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessMethod, onRequestFail);
    }

    function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {    
        var userLoginName = currentUser.get_loginName();
        var userTitle = currentUser.get_title();
        alert("Login Name: " + userLoginName);
        alert("Title: " + userTitle);        
    }

    function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
        alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

</script>
```

Comment: That did fix the User part of the script. Thanks. How could I save this information to a file on the server?

Comment: You can then save the information into a List. There are plenty of code on the web explaining how to use JSOM to add data into a list.